# Is pendulum only chaotic when its force is a single sinusoidal frequency?

Tags: chaos-theory

Chaotic systems will be chaotic under certain parameters, but when the forced, damped pendulum is discussed, the initial conditions of its position and velocity are only mentioned. Is it assumed that the force will *always* be a single sinusoidal frequency?

I did a quick Matlab simulation of the pendulum's EOMs where the input was a superposition of sine waves at different frequencies and the Poincaré plot yielded random behavior (no indication of periodic points or a pattern, just points scattered). I then created individual Poincaré plots for each of the frequencies used in the superposition; each outputted random behavior. Is this a reason why the force needs to be a single sinusoidal frequency?

Comment: What do you mean by the "force being sinusoidal"?

Comment: The force in the forced, damped EOM is generally of the form A*cos(w*t) where 'A' is the amplitude and 'w' is the driving frequency of the force. It's never a summation of cos(w_1*t)+....+cos(w_n*t) for 'n' frequencies. I will re-word the question to a single frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We always try to find the simplest model possible that manages to reflect the relevant characteristics of the real system. So whenever a sinusoidal forcing will do, it makes sense to adopt it.

Even if it looks random, the behavior of a system with complicated forcing is still deterministic by construction — but a messy response from a system subjected to a messy forcing is not surprising, much more interesting is how chaotic behavior emerges in simple systems.